# “Most of the trouble in the world is caused by people wanting to be important.” Is this a genuine TS Eliot quote?

Tags: quote-source, t-s-eliot

> Most of the trouble in the world is caused by people wanting to be important.

This quote has been attributed to TS Eliot, but I can't find any sources for it outside lists of inspirational quotes, and self-help books. Does anyone know if he did actually say or write this? If so, when/where?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not a word-for-word match, but in his 1949 work *The Cocktail Party*, Eliot wrote:

> Half of the harm that is done in this world is due to people who want
> to feel important.

The full text is available from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.16283/page/99/mode/2up).